# Any problem moving custom domain to iCloud when my Apple ID already uses that custom domain?

Tags: icloud, email

I have a custom domain **example.com** I use for email with Google Workspace.
My Apple ID is also on that domain.

I want to move example.com to iCloud+ but have seen mentions this is hard or impossible *when the Apple ID that purchased iCloud+* is already on the custom domain. E.g. my Apple ID is user@example.com.

Before I start I would like to be sure the migration is likely to succeed.

Has anyone moved a custom domain to iCloud+ that they were already using as the domain for their Apple ID, successfully? Any pitfalls or tips?

Comment: Ask Apple comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a Google Workspace mostly for email (formerly GSuite) for *myexample*.co.uk. I wanted to stop paying for stuff I don't use, and had access to a custom domain using iCloud+.  So in the past week I have moved *myexample*.co.uk to be my iCloud+ custom domain.

Works perfectly in Mac mail.

Does not work in Windows 11 mail on my VM, or in Outlook on Mac: the only email address those will work with (with necessary app specific password) is my original iCloud one - which I don't use as I changed my name on divorce and my original iCloud address is my married name.  Also won't work with smtp settings in, say, my router to send notifications.  Can't change my default iCloud address even though I don't use it for anything, and instead use my *myexample*.co.uk email address as my AppleID etc.

Does that add any useful info for you?

Comment: Were you able to import mails from Google Workspace to iCloud+? If yes, how long did it take? 
Using the 'Import Messages' option on iCloud Mail web interface and the import is now running for over a day for about 100 mails. Importing from MS365 Business.

Answer (score 1):

I was also using a custom domain as my Apple ID and I managed to set it up with iCloud+. Unfortunately, I think I had to make example@icloud.com the default address for Apple ID, removed example@myexame.com from my account and then set it up with iCloud+.

I might be wrong, but I think this is how I had to got about it last year.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't migrate my email directly from google to icloud - I did a Google Takeout of all my email and imported it on macmail, then moved the email I wanted to have in iCloud into iCloud mail folders.